# Github, remove all files from repository

Tags: github

How to delete all files and commits only from code in repository (but not delete anything from wiki)?

Comment: Note that the old commits will still be accessible by URL.  https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new empty branch, add whatever commits you want to replace the repo with, then `git push -f` that branch to overwrite the remote master.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new empty branch locally like this

```
git branch newbranch
```

Delete all the files in it, then commit that. This can then be pushed to the remote which will overwriting master:

```
git push -f origin newbranch:master
```

Comment: That won't delete commit history.